# How can I remove backslashes in django

Tags: python, django

I have data in database like this:

`John R/A` which is coming like `John R\/A` in template. I am getting that from JSON.

How can I remove the backslash in template in django?

Comment: Why are you not decoding the JSON?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams i am using `json.loads()` but i still get that character

Answer (score 0):

From [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape)

```
{% autoescape on %}
    {{ body }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: with `off` instead of `on`?

Comment: initially i had off , then i tried on as well but nothing chnaged